# Unknown CMake command "add_py_modules"

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-language

I'm setting up to build openage, a clone of AoE2 genie engine. My cmake command is not being processed. Is "add_py_modules" not possible here?

This is for windows 10, using vcpkg. Command used :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Software\vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# python module configurations

# python config file is created in libopenage
# in order to get options from libopenage
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(openage)
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)
add_py_modules(
__init__.py
__main__.py
assets.py
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.py
default_dirs.py
    NOINSTALL devmode.py
)
add_cython_modules(
cython_check.pyx
)

add_subdirectory(cabextract)
add_subdirectory(codegen)
add_subdirectory(convert)
add_subdirectory(cppinterface)
add_subdirectory(cvar)
add_subdirectory(event)
add_subdirectory(game)
add_subdirectory(log)
add_subdirectory(util)
add_subdirectory(renderer)
add_subdirectory(testing)
```

**Output**:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
CMake Warning at C:/Software/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:107 
(message):
There are no libraries installed for the Vcpkg triplet x64-windows.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Software/cmake-3.15.0-rc2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)

-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.21.27702.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.21.27702.2
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- 
works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- 
works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_py_modules):
Unknown CMake command "add_py_modules".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also 
"C:/Users/kafon/Desktop/openage/openage/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
PS C:\Users\kafon\Desktop\openage\openage\build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting

```
Unknown CMake command
```

error when configuring someone's else project usually means, that **wrong source directory** has been chosen.

In your case the correct source directory is the **top-level directory in the repository**, but you use its `openage` subdirectory. This is why you got the error.